# sql select,get most recent entry for each car

Tags: sql, mysql, database

My database (MySql) has 2 tables

Table 1 - contains a record for each car

cars= id(int), reg(int), type(int)

Table 2 - contains jobs for each car

jobs = id(int),date(date)

I need a SELECT command which will get me the most recent job for all id's

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that the whole database? Or are you simplifying it for us? If you have a job... and a car... they need to be related somehow...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have a shared field, you cant do this.  You need to store the associated car_id with each job, or have a jobs_to_cars table.

Then you'd use:

```
SELECT C.*, J.id, MAX(J.date)
FROM cars C 
INNER JOIN jobs J on J.car_id = C.id
GROUP BY C.id
```

If job's id IS the same as car's id then change j.car_id to j.id, but then you'd be lacking primary key on Jobs, which i suggest youd start making.

Comment: MySQL Error 1111: Invalid use of group function

Comment: issue with the max or the join? i explained why the join dont work, and i dont have time to test the max.  if you need a second query down there in where, or max up in the select then use it.

Comment: @jon_darkstar: what `J.id` do you expect to get in your query? Also your query will return **all jobs**, not just one per a car is OP asked.

Comment: or the simpler query i just put up works.  i was focused on the join issue and overlooked the group by clause

Comment: Thank you Don. jobs_id is actually the foreign key of cars_id. I created a primary key on the jobs table and used the second version of your code, it appears to be working thanks

Comment: date is right im not 100% if id's match.  i dont have means of testing now

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like this

```
SELECT c.*, MAX(j.date) date
FROM cars c 
   LEFT JOIN jobs j ON j.id = c.id
GROUP BY c.id
ORDER BY c.id
```

because you don't have other fields in [jobs]. If a car don't have any jobs, date will be NULL.

Answer (score 1):

```
    SELECT *
      FROM cars c
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) AS j_id
              FROM jobs
          GROUP BY car_id) x ON x.j_id = c.id
```

1. You forgot the `jobs.car_id` field, that specifies which car job belongs to
2. More elegant way will be to create the field `car.last_job_id` and maintain it with trigger on `jobs` table.

Since your question is not clear, this query also can be an answer:

```
    SELECT j.*
      FROM jobs j
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) id
              FROM jobs
          GROUP BY car_id) x ON x.id = j.id
```

Comment: Its nice that you assumed he forgot the jobs.car_id... I assumed there isn't a field to link... both are dangerous assumptions. I don't think adding a field would be what I'd consider elegant...

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
ORDER BY date DESC
```